# Xcode console missing outputs

Tags: ios, objective-c, node.js, xcode, nsurlrequest

I'm having this weird issue, when I try to `NSLog` an `NSMutableArray`, the console is only showing part of it... Here is my code:

```
+ (void)getCampgroundsWithServerURL:(NSString *)urlString
                    completionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL success, NSMutableArray *campgrounds))block {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"campgrounds"]];

    //HTTP GET Request
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"GET";
    [request addValue:@"campgrounds/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration* config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession* session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

    NSURLSessionDataTask* dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
        if (error == nil) {
            //store the data into an array
            NSMutableArray *CGs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL]];
            block(YES,CGs);
            NSLog(@"%@", CGs);
        } else {
            block(NO, nil);
        }
    }];

    [dataTask resume];
}
```

And this is the console output:

```
2016-10-16 12:24:36.492711 Yelp Camp[6452:1758068] (
    {
    "__v" = 0;
    "_id" = 57bc60c10ae5a01100e265e6;
    author =         {
        id = 57b9ce5df817403406fa58fb;
        username = gellert;
    };
    comments =         (
    );
    description = TestDescription;
    image = TestURL;
    name = Test;
},
    {
    "__v" = 2;
    "_id" = 57bd7868730c321100db974b;
    author =         {
        id = 57b9ce5df817403406fa58fb;
        username = gellert;
    };
    comments =         (
                    {
            "__v" = 0;
            "_id" = 57bd7896730c321100db974c;
            author =                 {
                id = 57b9ce5df817403406fa58fb;
                username = gellert;
            };
            text = "\U6f02\U4eae";
        },
                    {
            "__v" = 0;
            "_id" = 57bd78b3730c321100db974e;
            author =                 {
                id = 57bd78a3730
```

Clearly it's only printing half of the array... How's that possible? Is there a length limit for `NSLog`?

> Note: There is absolutely no problem with my database or server.

Comment: have you tried restarting xcode or even your mac?

Comment: @JaysonOng Yes, but it's not working.

Comment: I think your program is quitting before the logs have even finished writing. I have similar issues before. Try setting break point.